# Qpython dashboard

Tags: dashboard, qpython3

when I open qpython I cannot see the system or My python folders as described in " Getting started" in the qpython wiki. I have searched in vain for a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Were you using the QPython, not QPython3 ?  The guide is for QPython.

BTW: please read www.qpython.org instead of wiki.qpython.org in the future.